# Tidhttp fatalexception on android 6 device

Tags: android, google-maps, http, https, c++builder

I have a function loading a static map from google using tidhttp routine. This works great in android 5, but in  android 6 it throws an fatalexception. I know there are some culprits with tidhttp and https:// on android 6 (some posts about this here), but I use only http:// and get problems. Since I don't have any android 6 device at hand, I can't fully test this.

Has others had problems using tidhttp from android 6 device on google static map (http)? How did you solve it ?

--- 2015.07.21:

changes:

adding code where my problem is: I can't see any error in the TIdHTTPThread form... and it (as mentioned) functions in andriod5...

TIdHTTPThread.h

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

#ifndef IdHTTPThreadH
#define IdHTTPThreadH

#include <system.classes.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

class TDownloadThread : public TThread
{
protected:
    virtual void __fastcall Execute();

private:
    String searchString;

public:
     TMemoryStream *Strm;

    __fastcall TDownloadThread();

    __fastcall int setSearchString(String new_searchString);

};
#endif
```

IdHTTPThread.cpp

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma hdrstop

#include "IdHTTPThread.h"
#include <idhttp.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)

__fastcall TDownloadThread::TDownloadThread():TThread(true)
{
    FreeOnTerminate = true;
    Strm = new TMemoryStream;
    searchString ="";
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TDownloadThread::Execute()
{
    TIdHTTP *Http = new TIdHTTP(NULL);

    Http->Request->UserAgent="Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; FuelPumpFree)";

    Http->Get(searchString, Strm);

    Strm->Position=0;

}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

__fastcall int TDownloadThread::setSearchString(String new_searchString)
{
    searchString = new_searchString;

    return 0;
}
```

Below are the functions where the above code is used to extract the static map from google map api.

The code below is the needed definision in the headerfile for ViewMap.cpp

ViewMap.h:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef ViewMapH
#define ViewMapH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Sensors.Components.hpp>
#include <FMX.WebBrowser.hpp>
#include <FMX.TabControl.hpp>
#include <Firedac.Comp.Client.hpp>
#include <fmx.stdctrls.hpp> 

#include "IdHTTPThread.h"

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct str_mapdata
{
   float latitude;
   float longitude;
   int scale;
   String key;

};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

class TViewMapForm: public TRectangle
{
protected:

    TRectangle *badgerect, *lb_lat_rect, *lb_lon_rect, *mainrect, *hdrrect,
            *ftrrect;

    TButton *btn_pos_refresh, *btn_close;

    TImage *mapimage;   //Substitutes TWebbrowser which not aligns correctly.

    TShadowEffect *badgeshadow;
    TGlowEffect *badgeglow;

    TToolBar *tb_ftr;

    TFDMemTable *FDMemTable_localdata;

    TLabel *lb_longitude, *lb_latitude;

    TLocationSensor *locationsensor;

    //TWebBrowser *webbrowser;

    TTrackBar *tb_mapfocus;
    TSwitch *sw_focus;

    str_mapdata mapdata;

private:
    void __fastcall DownloadMap(float latitude, float longitude);
    void __fastcall DownloadMap(String mapstring);

    void __fastcall DownloadMapFinished(TObject *Sender);


public:

    __fastcall int updateMapData(float new_latitude, float new_longitude,
        String new_key);

    __fastcall int updateMap();

    __fastcall TViewMapForm(TComponent *Owner,
        TFDMemTable *FDMemTable_localdata);

    __fastcall void locationsensorchanged(TObject *Sender,
        const TLocationCoord2D &OldLocation,
        const TLocationCoord2D &NewLocation);

    __fastcall void mapfocustrackchange(TObject *Sender);

    __fastcall void btncloseclick(TObject *Sender);

    __fastcall void btnrefreshclick(TObject *Sender);

};



#endif
```

The code below is extracted from my project as it is...

Commenting with //<< To mark information

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma hdrstop

#include "FuelPumpUnit1.h"  //<<This is not included in this post
#include "ViewMap.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

__fastcall TViewMapForm::TViewMapForm(TComponent *Owner,
    TFDMemTable *new_FDMemTable_localdata):TRectangle(Owner)
{
    //Creating objects
    badgerect = new TRectangle(Owner);
    lb_latitude = new TLabel(Owner);
    lb_longitude = new TLabel(Owner);
    lb_lat_rect = new TRectangle(Owner);
    lb_lon_rect = new TRectangle(Owner);
    btn_pos_refresh = new TButton(Owner);
    btn_close = new TButton(Owner);
    hdrrect = new TRectangle(Owner);
    mainrect = new TRectangle(Owner);
    tb_ftr = new TToolBar(Owner);
    ftrrect = new TRectangle(Owner);

    //webbrowser = new TWebBrowser(Owner); << not used due to alignemt error
    mapimage = new TImage(Owner);

    locationsensor = new TLocationSensor(Owner);

    tb_mapfocus = new TTrackBar(Owner);

    //Copying information

    FDMemTable_localdata = new_FDMemTable_localdata;

    sw_focus=new TSwitch(Owner);

    sw_focus->Width = 50;
    sw_focus->IsChecked = false;
    sw_focus->Align = TAlignLayout::Left;

    //setting mapdata
    mapdata.latitude=0;
    mapdata.longitude=0;
    mapdata.scale=1;

    //Main headderrect
    hdrrect->Height = 50;
    hdrrect->Align = TAlignLayout::Top;
    hdrrect->Fill->Color=TAlphaColor(claBlack);

    //Main footerrect
    ftrrect->Height = 50;
    ftrrect->Align = TAlignLayout::Bottom;
    ftrrect->Fill->Color=TAlphaColor(claBlack);

    tb_ftr->Height = 50;
    tb_ftr->Align = TAlignLayout::Bottom;
    tb_ftr->TintColor=TAlphaColor(claBlack);
 // tb_ftr->Fill->Color=TAlphaColor(claBlack);

    tb_mapfocus->Align = TAlignLayout::Bottom;
    tb_mapfocus->Value = 5;
    tb_mapfocus->Min=5;
    tb_mapfocus->Max=15;
    tb_mapfocus->Frequency=1;
    tb_mapfocus->OnChange = &mapfocustrackchange;

    //Labelrect Latitude
    lb_lat_rect->Width=110;
    lb_lat_rect->Align=TAlignLayout::Right;
    lb_lat_rect->Fill->Color=TAlphaColor(claBlack);

    //Labelrect Longitude
    lb_lon_rect->Width=110;
    lb_lon_rect->Align=TAlignLayout::Right;
    lb_lon_rect->Fill->Color=TAlphaColor(claBlack);

    //Label latitude
    lb_latitude->StyledSettings = lb_latitude->StyledSettings >>
        TStyledSetting::Size >> TStyledSetting::Family >>
        TStyledSetting::Style >> TStyledSetting::FontColor >>
        TStyledSetting::Other;
    lb_latitude->Text="Latitude:\n000.000000";
    lb_latitude->Align=TAlignLayout::Client;
    lb_latitude->TextSettings->Font->Size=18;
    lb_latitude->TextSettings->FontColor=TAlphaColor(claYellow);

    //Label longitude
    lb_longitude->StyledSettings = lb_longitude->StyledSettings >>
        TStyledSetting::Size >> TStyledSetting::Family >>
        TStyledSetting::Style >> TStyledSetting::FontColor >>
        TStyledSetting::Other;
    lb_longitude->Text="Longitude:\n000.000000";
    lb_longitude->Align=TAlignLayout::Client;
    lb_longitude->TextSettings->Font->Size=18;
    lb_longitude->TextSettings->FontColor=TAlphaColor(claYellow);



    //Btn refresh
    btn_pos_refresh->Text = "Pos";
    btn_pos_refresh->Align = TAlignLayout::Left;
    btn_pos_refresh->StyleLookup="refreshtoolbutton";
    btn_pos_refresh->IconTintColor = TAlphaColor(claRed);
    btn_pos_refresh->Width = 48;
    btn_pos_refresh->OnClick = &btnrefreshclick;

    //Btn close
    btn_close->Text = "Cls";
    btn_close->Align = TAlignLayout::MostRight;
    btn_close->StyleLookup="replytoolbutton";
    btn_close->IconTintColor = TAlphaColor(claRed);
    btn_close->Images = FuelPumpForm->ImageList_buttons;
    btn_close->ImageIndex = 10;
    btn_close->Width = 55;
    btn_close->OnClick = &btncloseclick;

  //btn_pos_refresh->OnClick = &btn_pos_refresh_click;

    mainrect->Align=TAlignLayout::Client;
    mainrect->Fill->Color=TAlphaColor(claBlack);

    //webbrowser->Align = TAlignLayout::Client;
    mapimage->Align=TAlignLayout::Client;


    //Badgerect
    badgerect->Fill->Color=TAlphaColor(claBlack);
    badgerect->Stroke->Color=TAlphaColor(claNull);
    badgerect->Height=100;
    badgerect->Align=TAlignLayout::Client;

    //Padding
    badgerect->Padding->Top=5;
    badgerect->Padding->Bottom=5;
    badgerect->Padding->Left=5;
    badgerect->Padding->Right=5;

    //Margins
    badgerect->Margins->Top=15;
    badgerect->Margins->Left=15;
    badgerect->Margins->Right=15;
    badgerect->Margins->Bottom=5;

    badgeshadow = new TShadowEffect(Owner);
    badgeglow = new TGlowEffect(Owner);
    badgeglow->GlowColor = TAlphaColor(claWhite);


    this->Fill->Color=TAlphaColor(claNull);
    this->Stroke->Color=TAlphaColor(claNull);
    this->Stroke->Thickness=0;
    this->Height = 390;
    this->Position->Y=-100;
    this->Align=TAlignLayout::Top;

    badgerect->AddObject(badgeshadow);

    lb_lat_rect->AddObject(lb_latitude);
    lb_lon_rect->AddObject(lb_longitude);

    /*webbrowser->Navigate("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap"
    "?size=320x260&scale=1&zoom=15&maptype=roadmap&"
    "key=AIzaSyCjc63q60cIHgcpj0R88UsDBpmVEC9sVK4");
    */
//<< Line above disabled due to alingment errors with TWebBrowser component

    //mainrect->AddObject(webbrowser);
    mainrect->AddObject(mapimage);


    hdrrect->AddObject(btn_close);
    hdrrect->AddObject(btn_pos_refresh);
    hdrrect->AddObject(lb_lat_rect);
    hdrrect->AddObject(lb_lon_rect);

    //ftrrect->AddObject(tb_ftr);

    //ftrrect->AddObject(sw_focus);
    ftrrect->AddObject(tb_mapfocus);

    badgerect->AddObject(hdrrect);
    badgerect->AddObject(mainrect);
    badgerect->AddObject(ftrrect);

    this->AddObject(badgeglow);
    this->AddObject(badgerect);
    //this->AddObject(mainrect);



    locationsensor->OnLocationChanged=&locationsensorchanged;

    locationsensor->Active = true;

    //updateMap();
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

int __fastcall TViewMapForm::updateMapData(float new_latitude,
    float new_longitude, String new_key)
{
    mapdata.longitude = new_longitude;
    mapdata.latitude = new_latitude;
    mapdata.key = new_key;  //<<API key from Google

    AnsiString as_lattext, as_lontext;

    as_lattext.sprintf("Latitude:\n%010.6f",
    mapdata.latitude);

    as_lontext.sprintf("Longitude:\n%010.6f",
        mapdata.longitude);

    lb_latitude->Text=as_lattext;

    lb_longitude->Text=as_lontext;

}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TViewMapForm::DownloadMap(float latitude, float longitude)
{
    TDownloadThread *Thread = new TDownloadThread();
    Thread->OnTerminate = &DownloadMapFinished;

    Thread->setSearchString("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap"
        "?center="+FloatToStr(latitude)+
        ","+FloatToStr(longitude)+
        "&zoom=16&size=320x260&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red"
        "|label:?|"+FloatToStr(latitude)+","+
        FloatToStr(longitude)+"&key="+mapdata.key);

    Thread->Start();

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TViewMapForm::DownloadMap(String mapstring)
{
    TDownloadThread *Thread = new TDownloadThread();
    Thread->OnTerminate = &DownloadMapFinished;
    Thread->setSearchString(mapstring);
    Thread->Start();

}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TViewMapForm::DownloadMapFinished(TObject *Sender)
{
    TDownloadThread *Thread = static_cast<TDownloadThread *>(Sender);

    if(!Thread->FatalException)
        mapimage->Bitmap->LoadFromStream(Thread->Strm);  

//<< Line above fails with no good reason on Androd 6  
//Android 5 & 4 in the other hand... is OK!!  Why ? 

    else ShowMessage("Error loading map from Google!");
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall void TViewMapForm::locationsensorchanged(TObject *Sender,
    const TLocationCoord2D &OldLocation,
    const TLocationCoord2D &NewLocation)
{
    char LDecSeparator = FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator;
    FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator = '.';

    mapdata.longitude=NewLocation.Longitude;
    mapdata.latitude =NewLocation.Latitude;

    AnsiString as_lattext, as_lontext;

    as_lattext.sprintf("Latitude:\n%010.6f",
        NewLocation.Latitude);

    as_lontext.sprintf("Longitude:\n%010.6f",
        NewLocation.Longitude);

    lb_latitude->Text=as_lattext;

    lb_longitude->Text=as_lontext;

    locationsensor->Active=false;

    btn_pos_refresh->IconTintColor=TAlphaColor(claYellow);

    FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator = LDecSeparator;

    updateMap();

}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------- -

__fastcall int TViewMapForm::updateMap()
{
    char LDecSeparator = FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator;
    FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator = '.';

    String mapstring,midstring, lon_string, lat_string;

    mapstring = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap";

    //Adding size
    mapstring += "?size=320x260";

    //Adding scale
    mapstring +="&scale=1";

    //Adding zoom

    if(tb_mapfocus->Value>5)
    {
        mapstring += "&zoom="+IntToStr((int)tb_mapfocus->Value);

        if((FuelPumpForm->globaldata.region=="Region")
            &&(FuelPumpForm->globaldata.road=="Road"))
        {
            mapstring += "&center="+FloatToStr(mapdata.latitude)+","+
            FloatToStr(mapdata.longitude);
        }
    }

    //Adding type
    mapstring +="&maptype=roadmap";

    //You marker

    if((FuelPumpForm->globaldata.region=="Region")
        &&(FuelPumpForm->globaldata.road=="Road"))
    {
        mapstring += "&markers=color:black|label:X|"+
        FloatToStr(mapdata.latitude)+","+FloatToStr(mapdata.longitude);
    }


    //if(FDMemTable_localdata)
    {
        FDMemTable_localdata->First();

        int cnt = FDMemTable_localdata->RecordCount;

        FuelPumpForm->addLog("Map points: "+IntToStr(cnt));

        FuelPumpForm->addLog("Map maxpts: "+IntToStr(FuelPumpForm->globaldata.maxbadgeview));

        if (cnt>FuelPumpForm->globaldata.maxbadgeview) cnt=FuelPumpForm->globaldata.maxbadgeview;

        FuelPumpForm->addLog("Map counts: "+IntToStr(cnt));

        for (int i = 0; i<cnt; i++)
        {
            FuelPumpForm->addLog("Map iterator: "+IntToStr(i));
            try{
                midstring = "&markers=size:mid|color:";

                String s_rank;
                int rank;

                float since = FDMemTable_localdata->FieldByName("since")->AsFloat;

//              since = 0.0;

                s_rank = FDMemTable_localdata->
                    FieldByName("rank")->AsString;


                if(since<12.0)
                {
                    midstring += "green"; ;
                }
                else if ((since>=12.0)&&(since<36.0))
                {
                    midstring += "yellow";
                }
                else if ((since>=36.0)&&(since<168.0))
                {
                    midstring += "red";
                }
                else
                {
                    midstring += "gray";
                }



                try
                {


                    midstring += "|label:"+IntToStr(StrToInt(s_rank));
                }
                catch(...)
                {
                    midstring += "|label:"+s_rank;
                }

                midstring += "|";

                lat_string.sprintf(L"%.4f",FDMemTable_localdata->
                    FieldByName("latitude")->AsFloat);

                midstring+=lat_string+",";

                lon_string.sprintf(L"%.4f",FDMemTable_localdata->
                    FieldByName("longitude")->AsFloat);

                midstring+=lon_string;

            }
            catch(...)
            {
                midstring="";

                ShowMessage("Error in calculating map data");

                FDMemTable_localdata->Next();

                continue;
            }

            mapstring +=midstring;

            //FuelPumpForm->addLog(mapstring);

            FDMemTable_localdata->Next();
        }

    }
    mapstring +="&key="+mapdata.key;



    FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator = LDecSeparator;

    //webbrowser->Navigate(mapstring);
    DownloadMap(mapstring);

    FuelPumpForm->addLog("Map: "+mapstring);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

__fastcall void TViewMapForm::mapfocustrackchange(TObject *Sender)
{
    updateMap();
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

__fastcall void TViewMapForm::btncloseclick(TObject *Sender)
{
    this->Visible=false;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

__fastcall void TViewMapForm::btnrefreshclick(TObject *Sender)
{

    btn_pos_refresh->IconTintColor=TAlphaColor(claYellow);
    //locationsensor->Active = true;
    mapdata.longitude = FuelPumpForm->globaldata.mylongitude;
    mapdata.latitude = FuelPumpForm->globaldata.mylatitude;
    AnsiString as_lattext, as_lontext;

    as_lattext.sprintf("Latitude:\n%010.6f",
        mapdata.latitude);

    as_lontext.sprintf("Longitude:\n%010.6f",
        mapdata.longitude);

    lb_latitude->Text=as_lattext;

    lb_longitude->Text=as_lontext;

    updateMap();

}
```

Comment: What is the actual exception that is being raised? Is it an HTTP error, a socket error, an OS error, or something else? AFAIK, `TIdHTTP` (and Indy in general) works fine on Android 6. And FYI, it is possible to use `TIdHTTP` with HTTPS on Android 6 if you are willing to install updated OpenSSL libs with your app.

Comment: In my Tidhttp configuration I used this in the useragent: "Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; nameofapp)" where nameofapp is the name of my app.

Comment: That is not what I asked. Are you saying that change solves your error? Or is causing the error?

Comment: Since I don't have any Android 6 device at hand, I am not sure of the type of error raised.

Comment: Then there is no way to help you without knowing what is actually going wrong. There are too many possibilities.

Comment: Just wondering if anyone else have had similar experience that tidhttp failed on android 6 but ok on android 5 on http request.

Comment: Sorry... think we are crosspassing Messages here (sorry for that) (I'm on a bad mobile link...). The situation is not solved. What I meant was, could my useragent setting above cause that the Tidhttp request is ok on android 5 but causes an error on android 6 ?

Comment: I can't answer that, since you are not able to provide the actual error message. Too many things could be going wrong, you need to narrow it down. However, in general, the `UserAgent` has no effect on the *client side*, but it may have an effect on the *server-side*, if the server decides to send different content to different client types. But if have an Android 5 client and an Android 6 client accessing the same URL with the same `UserAgent`, the server should behave the same way for both clients.

Comment: Thanx Remy. When I'm at my computer again, I can try to post the code here where my googleapi code is faulting on Android 6. ☺

Comment: The error occures DownLoadMapFinished where the FatalException variable is set Has things changed with Android 6 and parallel programming, or the use of TIdHTTP in android 6

Comment: Refrease: The FatalException variabel is set only in Android 6, not in Android 4&5. Has TIdHTTP changed for android 6 ? By the way, it is progrmmed in XE8/AppMethod 1.17

Comment: When `FatalException` is set, it means an uncaught exception was raised inside the thread. What is the actual `ClassType` and `Message` of the `FatalException`? Most likely, an HTTP error or SSL/TLS error is being raised. Also, in the code you have shown, you are leaking the `Strm` object, and an uncaught exception will leak the `TIdHTTP` object. You should be creating both objects in the thread constructor and freeing them both in the thread destructor (which you don't even have!)

Comment: You have right, it leaks... but it is it enough to raise an exception only on android 6?

Comment: until you can say what the actual `ClassType` and `Message` of the `FatalException` are, I can't tell you what is going wrong. There are too many possibilities to speculate.

Comment: Okay... I'll try to change the code in my next release, so I can reveal the message... Or I could make a test case  and try to run it on a Android 6 device (such I don't have at hand at the moment).

Comment: So is it, going blind in my own text... discovered that it was NOT http:// but https:// in my request. Did change this in the last release to tighten security on the googleapi call. Therefore I am a victim for the lack of indys tidhttp support on BoringSSL...

Comment: There have been some updates to Indy to account for BoringSSL, so make sure you are using the absolute latest version of Indy. If it still does not work, you will have to deploy the [Android 6 compatible OpenSSL `.so` files](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/) with your app and use those instead..

Comment: Thanx for good help Remy! And of course I will cleanup my code and add destructors...

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry... my request to static maps actually used https:// not http://. Changing it to http:// will most likely solve the problem. This will be done on my next release of my product. But it introduces a securityrisk. ..

Comment: I will check this as an 'answer' when I can confirm it on an Android 6...